# Storyboard Refreshing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, storyboard

In my app I have a score label and a few animations. Now, when my animations collide the score should increase by one in which case it currently does. However, their is one issue, when these two images collide and one point is added to the score, for some reason my app glitches slightly, and these animations they were previously moving cease and disappear. After doing some research and extensive problem solving, I have come to conclude that because the score label changes size due to the numbers increasing, this is causing the storyboard to refresh and revert all images to their original positions. As for the animations, I believe this refresh is causing them to stop, and makes the app think that the images have not been told to animate.

To further reinforce my assumption that the storyboard is refreshing. I have changed the code so that when the images collide, the score increase by `score += 0`, in which case the score does not increase it stays at zero. When this happens my app's animations continue correctly and no glitches occur. So for some reason, any integer greater than zero does not work. Additionally, to prevent the storyboard from refreshing, I have made the score label's text field quite big, so that any integer may fit in there and not change the actual size of the text field.

Finally, I have tried many things to fix this issue, but have unfortunately not come across a solution.

This is the score code.

```
// Score Setup
   score += 0
   scoreValueRight.text = "\(score)"
```

Comment: Changes the size of UILabel doesnt make sense that your UI is refreshed. Hopefully U have somthg different mistake, Pls check and clearfy.

Comment: I have literally tried everything, and can't find a fix.

Comment: Pls add your UI images where u getting the issue and related source code also.

Comment: They are just two image views that upon colliding glitch out and disappear, only when the score label has constraints on it.

Comment: Show me what you have done.

Comment: did you check your score is increasing or not?

Comment: Yes it does. In the original post I provided it clearly won't because score increment is zero. However, when I provide an integer greater than zero, it increases by the specified amount.

Comment: Obviously it increases as the internal text increases.

Comment: Correct. But for some reason, when I constraint the score label, the score will increase by one, and then thats it, no images are moving. But when I do the same thing, except this time the score label is not constrained, all the animations work and the score continues to increase when they collide.

Comment: Add your UI images. Show us what you have done in UI.

Comment: Added in original post.

Comment: add a gif if you can, it will help your case

Comment: Any suggestions?